# Custom Invoke Extension For Simple Cross Thread Calls Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, extension-methods, data-conversion

I have read the following article and I'm very interested in a vb.net version of this.

[Microsoft Example Of Generic Method to safely perform Cross-Thread Invoke](http://tech.pro/blog/1101/generic-method-to-safely-perform-cross-thread-)

I wish to have an **extension method** to simplify and reduce the amount of delegate code that I would need to write for a backgroundworker / UI update task using delegates. I would like GET and SET methods.

I have tried the usual code covertors on google by telerik and developer fusion with no luck. Developer fusion just hangs and telerik gives me code which I cant get working as it has intellisense errors. I think this will need a human conversion and I would be very grateful for any help.

Could anyone post me some vb.net code to make this happen.

E.g. a text box and a .Text property or a combobox and a seletedvalue property.

I have seen a SET method here
[VB.net avoiding cross thread exception with extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683473/vb-net-avoiding-cross-thread-invoke-geniusexception-with-extension-method)

But unfortunately I don't think there is a GET method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks really weird to my brain...but try something like this out:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Task.Run(Sub()
                     Dim txt As String = TextBox1.InvokeGet(Function(tb) tb.Text)
                     Label1.InvokeSet(Sub(l) l.Text = "Hello " & txt)
                 End Sub)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Module Module1

    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub InvokeSet(Of T As ISynchronizeInvoke)(ByVal control As T, ByVal toPerform As Action(Of T))
        If control.InvokeRequired Then
            control.Invoke(toPerform, New Object() {control})
        Else
            toPerform(control)
        End If
    End Sub

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function InvokeGet(Of T As ISynchronizeInvoke)(ByVal control As T, ByVal toPerform As Func(Of T, Object))
        If control.InvokeRequired Then
            Return control.Invoke(toPerform, New Object() {control})
        Else
            Return toPerform(control)
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Fantastic! It works thank you very much.  I'm new to this site so I can't class this as the answer or upvote it as I don't have enough reputation or something.

Comment: No problem.  Glad it helped.  I don't remember exactly how it works in the beginning.  After a certain amount of time, or points, you can come back and uptick and/or accept posts that you like.